# Building your R package inside a Docker container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, gitlab

You've probably heard that writing your R code as a package makes certain aspects of development easier, such as dependency management, testing, and documentation. The [golem](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem) package is built upon treating your Shiny app as a R package.
On the other hand, I've worked on Shiny apps that run inside Docker containers, as part of Gitlab CI/CD. Turning the app into a package seems confusing to set-up in Docker later, since you have to load a package that doesn't exist on CRAN, yet you have to install it somehow.
How can one build a Docker image that runs a local package? Hosting the package itself is not an option if it's proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging around, I think I've found a way to merge these approaches. We want to keep the source code in our repo as the latest version, so we don't want to build our package outside of Docker, and then feed it into containers. Instead, we'll copy the source code into a container, then build and install our package there! And after that, we'll simply load the package and call a function that runs our Shiny app.

Here's the Docker image with comments:

```
FROM rocker/r-base:latest

# Copy all code in a specific folder
COPY . ./package_code

# Install the packages used in our app, PLUS the pkgbuild package that will, as the name suggests, build our package
RUN install2.r --ncpus -1 pkgbuild \
    shiny stringr 

# Build the package into a file named in dest_path:
RUN R -e "pkgbuild::build(path = 'package_code', binary = FALSE, dest_path = 'package_code/MyPackage.tar.gz')"

# Install a local (non-CRAN) package for later use:
RUN R -e "install.packages('package_code/MyPackage.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"

# Expose a certain port. This should be the same as the port in your my_app() function
EXPOSE 1111

# Run a simple script that loads our package and runs the app
CMD ["Rscript", "package_code/run_final_app.R"]
```

run_final_app.R is a script in the root of our package directory, with contents:

```
library(MyPackage)
MyPackage::myapp()
```

And finally, myapp() should be structured something like this:

```
myapp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    ...
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ...
    })
  }

  # the host and port are important. The port should be the same as the one in the Docker image
  shinyApp(ui, server) |> runApp(host ="0.0.0.0", launch.browser = F, port = 1111)
}
```

That's all! My main motivation for writing this was that I couldn't find a similar resource online. Furthermore, I kept seeing devtools::build() as the recommended function, but no matter what I tried, it wouldn't install inside a docker container. Then I found that the build() is just a function exported from pkgbuild, which installed smoothly.

Hope this helps you, let me know how it goes!